# Is there a pair of two $2 \times 2$ complex matrices that are never simultaneously conjugate to real matrices

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

The problem is as in the title.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2 \times 2$ complex matrices. Are there $A,B$ such that  for any $2 \times 2$ matrix $C$, either  $CAC^{-1}$ or $CBC^{-1}$  is never real. A numerical example I think I found would be:

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -4-i \sqrt{29} \\
 \frac{8}{9}+\frac{1}{9} \left(-4-i \sqrt{29}\right) & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -9 \\
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
However, I do not know how to show that it actually works. It is a candidate as Mathematica could not find the conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $A=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}\pmatrix{1&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{z\\ \overline{z}}\pmatrix{1&1}$ where $z$ has nonzero real and imaginary parts. Note that all of $A,B$ and $AB$ have real spectra. However, since $\operatorname{tr}(AB^2)=z(z+\overline{z})$ is non-real, $A$ can $B$ cannot be both similar to real matrices via the same similarity transform.

(By adding some appropriate real scalar multiples of $I$ to $A$ and $B$, one can create counterexamples with invertible $A$ and $B$ as well, although $AB$ will then have only a real trace but not necessarily a real spectrum.)